# Redirect content of /dev/ttySDIO0 to a file

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, tty

Is there any way to redirect the content of a tty device (/dev/ttySDIO0) file so that its content can be managed using a file IO operations. I don't prefer to use 'cat' here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) which can connect to a tty on one side with a lot of command line options, and the other end can be pretty much anything that accepts read/write or send/receive call. From the above link :

> Socat is a command line based utility
>   that establishes two bidirectional
>   byte streams and transfers data
>   between them. Because the streams can
>   be constructed from a large set of
>   different types of data sinks and
>   sources (see address types), and
>   because lots of address options may be
>   applied to the streams, socat can be
>   used for many different purposes.

Comment: Yes, it looks like socat is an useful tool.  
  
I installed & used socat as:
`socat /dev/ttySDIO0,raw,echo=0,crnl ./myfile`   
  
Then tried read/write on myfile, however that did not reflect in   ttySDIO0. Not sure if I am using it correctly.

Comment: Why not use read/write directly  on the tty ? Alternatively, you can use socat to make a link with a process, instead of a file

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Direct read/write did not work for me. May be I need to hack the driver to add file operations, as in the driver version which I am using (2.6.29) does not have any file operations.

Comment: The SDIO driver in  Linux Kernel Version 2.6.34 has file_operations structure added which has .read operation exposed. I think, this will be useful, however this would require Android upgrade.

Comment: In the later kernel version 2.6.32 I could use the File IO on tty devices, only after I set the tty type to raw as: stty -F /dev/ttySDIO0 raw. Thank you shodanex, for the help!